# CSS cogged right border

Tags: css, border, curves

Having the situation described in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJmPP.jpg), I need to find solution for such a border using CSS-only, if it is possible. The height is not fixed, it can be variable. And the border should start and end like it is shown. And there is a border for that wavy line.

Red color on the screen is just to show you how it works.

I need this to work on IE9+.

Comment: And where did you get stuck, how far did you get, what's your HTML?

Comment: I've tried to adopt this solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/artDy But it can't help because I need to have border color, but not just to subtract some from my box with different background color.

Answer (score 0):

IE 9+ is difficult, since [`border-image`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp) property won't work here...

If you can do it withour proper endings, you can just use the `border-color` in combination with a background image, that is y-repeated and right aligned.

Comment: Thank you, I know it is possible to do that  with border image without proper endings. Do you know the solution for other browsers?

Comment: With border-image, proper endings are possible (in case i didn't made that clear...), but with the repeated background approach not. Now what solution do you mean?